# JSF render does not work

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, jsf-2.2, wildfly

The following code does not rerender the form:

xhtml:

```xhtml
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="form">
            <rich:panel header="My Header">
                <h2>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{tournamentBean.mode}" />
                </h2>
                <a4j:commandButton value="Toggle"
                    action="#{tournamentBean.toggleMode()}" render="form" />
            </rich:panel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Named("tournamentBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TournamentBean implements Serializable {

  private String mode = "A";

  public String getMode() {
    return mode;
  }

  public void toggleMode() {
    if (this.mode.equals("A"))
      this.mode = "B";
    else
      this.mode = "A";
  }
}
```

I am using Wildfly 8.0 and therefore JSF 2.2. The method toggleMode is called on every click on the button. In IE 11 it never rerenders the form. In Chrome it works twice but not more times.

What am I missing?

Comment: Although `render="form"` should work, though with RichFaces only, as it uses `UIComponent#findComponent()` method to locate components, it is plain inefficient, and `render="@form"` should always be used to rerender the current form.

Comment: Show your "/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml", may it contain by any chance an extra h:form around <ui:include name="content"/> ?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. `render="@from"' did not help. And the default.xhtml is very simple. No form or anything special.

Comment: it works with h:commandButton. Any ideas why?

Answer (score -1):

`@Named` is CDI annotation, `@ViewScoped` is from JSF. So you have both CDI and JSF trying to manage the bean, so of course this wont work and the result bean scope can be singleton, if its going to work at all.

Replace `@ViewScoped` with for example `@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` and try running the code. If you need to use view scope, look around for CDI implementation or `conversationscope`. It can be done somehow even though CDI doesnt directly support `viewscope`.

Or migrate to JSF and its `@ManagedBeans`, but those are sheduled to be depracated.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with the ViewScoped declaration that the OP has used. There are two ViewScoped annotations - one belonging to javax.faces.bean (old) and javax.faces.view (new & CDI compliant).

Comment: First of all, `@ViewScoped` faces annotation works with JSF only when it goes with `@ManagedBean`, which is not the case (JSF scopes can be used with CDI annotations as well). Appart from that, there's Omnifaces' own [`@ViewScoped`](http://wiki.omnifaces.googlecode.com/hg/javadoc/org/omnifaces/cdi/ViewScoped.html) annotation which is supposed to work with CDI (even not necessary in OP's case, as he's using JSF 2.2). And, for your last sentence, about JSF managed beans scheduled to be deprecated, you're missing a link that actually confirms that. A useless answer IMHO: -1.